# Difference between pandas .iloc and .iat?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've recently noticed that a function where I iterate over a `DataFrame` rows using `.iloc` is very slow. I found out that there's a faster method called `.iat`, that's said to be equivalent to `.iloc`. I tried it and it cut the run time down by about 75%.

But I'm a little hesitant: why is there an "equivalent" method that's faster? There must be some difference between the inner workings of these two and a reason why they both exist and not just the faster one. I've tried looking everywhere but even the pandas documentation just states that

> **DataFrame.iat**
>   Fast integer location scalar accessor.
>
> Similarly to iloc, iat provides integer based lookups. You can also set using these indexers.

And that doesn't help.

Are there limits to using `.iat`? Why is faster; is it sloppier? Or do I just switch to using `.iat` and happily forget `.iloc` ever existed?

Comment: `.iat` working only with scalar, `.iloc` working with scalar + df, series -> more general -> slowier

Comment: Cautionary note:  if you are iterating over rows very often, the issue is not `at` vs ` loc` but rather that you should rarely be iterating over rows in the first place  ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`iat` and `at` working with scalar only, so very fast. Slower, more general functions are `iloc` and `loc`.

You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting):

> Since indexing with **[]** must handle a lot of cases (single-label access, slicing, boolean indexing, etc.), it has a bit of overhead in order to figure out what you’re asking for. If you only want to access a scalar value, the fastest way is to use the **at** and **iat** methods, which are implemented on all of the data structures.
>
> Similarly to **loc**, at provides label based scalar lookups, while, **iat** provides integer based lookups analogously to **iloc**.

Answer (score 7):

`iat` and `at` gives only a **single value** output, while `iloc` and `loc` can give **multiple row** output. 
 Example: 
 `iloc[1:2,5:8]` is valid but `iat[1:2,5:8]` will throw error

Comment: Can you explain the answer in brief? Please also see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: this is the real answer!