# Python: for cycle in range over files

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a list that takes values from different files.
I have three dataframes called for example "df1","df2","df3"
each files contains two columns with data, so for example "df1" looks like this:

```
0, 1
1, 4
7, 7
```

I want to create a list that takes a value from first row in second column in each file, so it should look like this

```
F=[1,value from df2,value from df3]
```

my try

```
 import pandas as pd
 df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
 df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
 df3 = pd.read_csv(file3)


 F=[]
 for i in range(3):
   F.append(df{"i"}[1][0])
```

probably that is not how to iterate over, but I cannot figure out the correct way

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` and list comprehension

```
vals = [df.iloc[0, 1] for df in [df1,df2,df3]]
```

`iloc` will get value from first row (index 0) and second column (index 1). If you wanted, say, value from *third* row and *fourth* column, you'd do `.iloc[2, 3]` and so forth.

As suggested by @jpp, you may use `iat` instead:

```
vals = [df.iat[0, 1] for df in [df1,df2,df3]]
```

For difference between them, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426875/difference-between-pandas-iloc-and-iat) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `.iat` which is designed for fast scalar access.